# How to use one image as full page background

Tags: html, jquery, css, user-interface

Please check below web template image.
URL - https://ibb.co/cD3iH8

I am expecting to use above abstract design image as background for a whole page.

kindly share the best approach to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried and [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Multiple options here. You can play around with:

```
background-size: 100%
```

or

```
background-size: cover
```

or

```
background-size: contain
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use body height same as image height:

```
body{
  background-image:url('https://image.ibb.co/iGhzqT/atach_6.png');
  height:5788px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/YvvJWb

Comment: I'm not sure that solution is mobile friendly... I would look for 100% width and aspect ratio... [Some reading here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette first he didn't ask for mobile and yes it is mobile friendly.second it's not necessary to set width to 100%. by default  body tag is 100%. so this is not reason to down vote

Answer (score 1):

add

```
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-size:contain;
```

to your style sheet .it will works fine .I'm added the snippet below

```css
body{
  background:url('https://image.ibb.co/iGhzqT/atach_6.png');
  height:6000px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  background-size:contain;
  width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  
</body
```